# Display each result one by one

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a code which increases a URL parameter in a while loop until $i is equal to 10. When this happens, it will display each number up to 10 (as this is when $i stops increasing) - in this case it would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

The problem with this is that only when $i is equal to 10 does it show 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 - I need it to display the numbers as it happens (rather than waiting for $i to equal 10!).

```
<div id="here"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test2.php",
            success: function(data) { $("#here").html(data);  }
        });
});
</script>
```

test2.php:

```
while($content = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com?id='.$i)) {
   if($i !== 1000000) {
      echo $i;
   }else{
      break;
   }
   $i++;
}
```

---

I have found out that the code below would be useful to solve my problem, however it would take me forever to write out 1 to 1000000 in the `arr`:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

$({}).queue("ajax", $.map(arr, function(item, i) {
  return function(next) {
    return $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "test2.php",
              data: {n:item}
           })
           .then(function(data) { 
             $("#here").append(data);  
             next();
           });

  }
})).dequeue("ajax")
```

test2.php:

```
if (isset($_POST["n"])) {
  $content = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com?id=" . $_POST["n"]);
  echo $content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you write a loop to get that array ?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.......];
```

I know that this will not solve your problem (question), but remember that you are trying to lear something in here... and you should know that simple loop will save you time.

Comment: As I mentioned, it would take forever to write all the way up to 1000000

Comment: That doesnt seem to work as I have to loop like 1000000 and the page doesnt load

Comment: I get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: to get that to work you need to use intervals like @Kld said

Answer (score 0):

You can use use setInterval to make an ajax call each second this way.

```
function getData(val) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test2.php",
    data: {n: val}
    success: function(data) {
      $("#here").html(data);
    }
  });
}


var x = 1; // initial value
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {

  getData(x);

  if (++x === 1000000) { // 10000000 is the last value
    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
}, 1000); //1000 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple for-loop instead of creating an unnecessary array:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test2.php",
        data: { n: i},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#here").html(data); 
        }
    }); 
}
```